# Button not Clicking - Selenium Web Driver using java

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please find the Below Html Code

```
<td class=" center-align" style="padding:10px 0 0 0;" colspan="3">
<span data-bind="visible: !editing()" style="display: none;"></span>
<input id="btnSaveUserProfile" class="orange-but" type="button" data-bind="visible: editing, click:$root.btnSaveUserProfile" value="Save" style="">
<input id="lblEditCancel" class="orange-but" type="button" data-bind="click: EditCancel" value="Cancel">
</td>
```

below are my Java code (Selenium Webdriver) to click the Save Button ("btnSaveUserProfile")

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btnSaveUserProfile")).click();
```

but during the Execution not clicking same errors not occurred, case was passed without click action

Please refer the html code and give an suggestion to solve this

Comment: Why do you want to click on textbox ?

Comment: This is Submit Button not an textbox Refer the type attribute

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: i'm not getting any errors

Comment: It might be becz of multiple elements present with that same id ... If you have Firepath installed or some add-on which can check xpath, can you check how many elements are returned by this xpath : **//*[@id='btnSaveUserProfile']**

Comment: Before clicking button are you sure you are in correct tab?

Answer (score 0):

try to execute the click action using javascriptexecutor

```
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", driver.findElement(By.id("btnSaveUserProfile")));
```

Comment: thanks already tried, but its not clickable, note this button was located inside the tabs (application have an multiple tabs and in particular tabs these two buttons are available)

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you pl try with the below code, i have included wait statement.

WebDriver Driver;  
 WebDriverWait wait =null; 
 public void function()
 {
  wait=new WebDriverWait(Driver,90);
  WebElement buttonclick=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("btnSaveUserProfile")));
  buttonclick.click();
 }
```